# Array clears after assignment "Array have Select values"

Tags: javascript

I create an array 'userSelects' with 'select's from an 'option' array, the 'option' array is created with my usernamesunits array.

If I start the function at the first time, it works, but the elements are removed from my array.

running MySQL 5 with php7.3, I use a local server and a webspace.

```
//  Main Tet
    let testSelect = document.createElement("select");
    let testOption = document.createElement("option");
    testSelect.id = "1";
    testOption.text = "alle";
    testSelect.add(testOption);

    let name = document.createElement("select");
    let nameOption = document.createElement("option"); 
    let n1ameOption = document.createElement("option"); 

    name.id = "2";
    nameOption.text = "--none--";
    name.add(nameOption);

    nameOption = document.createElement("option"); 
    nameOption.text = userSafe[0].name;
    name.add(nameOption);


    n1ameOption.text = userSafe[1].name;
    name.add(n1ameOption);


    document.body.appendChild(name);
    document.body.appendChild(testSelect);

    //  onchange womit die user id übergeben wird
    // 
    name.addEventListener("change",function(){
        console.log("tabe :" + name.value);
        test(name.selectedIndex - 1 ,testSelect.id);
    });

function test(id,oldID){
    //  r is a new test select
    r = document.getElementById(oldID);
    r.length = 0;

    var sicherheitsCopy = userSelects;
    sicherheitsCopy = userSelects;



    //  wen option select hinzugefügt wird, wird es gelöscht von der userSelect[index]
    for(let index = 0; sicherheitsCopy[id].length != 0; index){
        r.add(sicherheitsCopy[id][0])
        console.log("index nummer " + sicherheitsCopy[id].length);
    }
}


//  generate userSelects
function initUnitSelect(){
    for(let index = 0; index < userSafe.length; ++index){
        let testSelect = document.createElement("select");
        let userOptionFirstUnit = document.createElement("option");
        userOptionFirstUnit.text = "--none--";
        testSelect.add(userOptionFirstUnit);

        for(let index2 = 0; index2 < userUnitsCase[index][0].length; ++index2){
            let userOption = document.createElement("option");

            userOption.text = userUnitsCase[index][0][index2];
            testSelect.add(userOption);
        }
        userSelects[index] = testSelect;
        console.log("userSelects " + userSelects );
    }
}
```

for an example, my test subdomain

https://twliste.deutschritter.eu/offiziersliste/
the first button show what I mean.

//edit i forget to post a code

```
//  Global Variable
var sfgID = "sfg";
var counter = 0;            //  count fot hte sfgID
var supCounter = 0;         //  count for the supID
var supZeilenCounter = 0;   //  count the row in the table for the user unit
var testCounter = 0;

var sfgSupGroup = 5;        //sup Tables
var sfgSupMembergroupe = 5; //Table rows

//  Global URL
var getUserInformationURL = "https://twliste.deutschritter.eu/offiziersliste/php_interface/get_user_info.php";

var userSafe = [];           //  save all user with user informations
var userUnitsCase = [];      // save all userUnits, 
var userSelects = [];        //  save userSelects Index == userSafe Array Index
```

Comment: Where have you defined your userSelects variable? I think first you need to define it. Also, instead of using this userSelects[index] = testSelect;, i'll suggest you to take a look at push function of arrays in js

Comment: sure, i use it but it not works..

```javascript
    var sicherheitsCopy = [];
    sicherheitsCopy.push(userSelects);
    console.log(sicherheitsCopy[0][0].length);

    for(let index = 0; sicherheitsCopy[0][0].length != 0; index){
        r.add(sicherheitsCopy[0][0][id])
        //console.log("index nummer " + sicherheitsCopy[id].length);
    }

```
The logs : 
Bevor for userselects copy : 5 
Bevor for sicherheits copy : 5 
After for userselects copy : 0 
After for sicherheits copy : 0